# Error on setting PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to False in $PDO_OPTIONS

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I am using [phpactiverecords](http://www.phpactiverecord.org) with codeigniter. I want to set PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false

I am adding **`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false`** to **`$PDO_OPTIONS`** in file `../lib/Connection.php` at line54. It is causing uncaught exception at:

```
../lib/adenter code hereapters/MysqlAdapter.php(76): ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SET NAMES ?', Array)
```

any idea?

**Exception**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with
>   message `'42000, 1064, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '?' at line 1`' in
>   /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php:304

**Stack trace:**

```
0) /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/adapters/MysqlAdapter.php(76): ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SET NAMES ?', Array)

1) /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php(108): ActiveRecord\MysqlAdapter->set_encoding('utf8')

2) /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/ConnectionManager.php(33): ActiveRecord\Connection::instance('mysql://root:@l...')

3) /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Table.php(103): ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::get_connection(NULL)

4) /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/s in /home/waqas/apps/FBI-PHP/sparks/php-activerecord/0.0.2/vendor/php-activerecord/lib/Connection.php on line 304
```

Comment: WHAT exception it cause?

Comment: I have added exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to set the connection encoding is the `charset` attribute within the connection DSN:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foo;charset=utf8';
$conn = new PDO($dsn, 'jim', '12345678', $options);
```

... but this feature requires PHP/5.3.6 or greater. Your library possibly tries to support older versions so runs a SQL command instead. The detail is that you need to run exactly this:

```
SET names=utf8
```

Quoting the argument will not work:

```
SET names='utf8'
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''

The library is using prepared statements to run the query. Here's [the offending code](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/adapters/MysqlAdapter.php#L73):

```
public function set_encoding($charset)
{
    $params = array($charset);
    $this->query('SET NAMES ?',$params);
}
```

Since `utf8` is a string, it technically needs to be quoted. So (in theory) you cannot used prepared statements to run such query. In practice, it apparently works fine if you use emulated prepared statements, but not in you use the native ones:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$user = 'test';
$pass = 'test';

// Works fine
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
));
$res = $pdo->prepare('SET NAMES ?');
$res->execute(array('utf8'));
unset($pdo);

// Triggers SQL syntax error
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
));
$res = $pdo->prepare('SET NAMES ?');
$res->execute(array('utf8'));
unset($pdo);
```

My conclusion is that you're out of luck if you want to use the library as-is: PHP ActiveRecord does not seem to support native prepared statements.

However, it's possible that a simple patch would do the trick:

```
// Completely untested!
public function set_encoding($charset)
{
    $this->query('SET NAMES ' . $charset);
}
```

**Edit:** I've seen your [bug report](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/issues/367). You omit the exception message there as well. Please note that error messages exist to help you: you should never discard them!

Comment: you are totally right. Issue was in php-activerecord/lib/adapters/MysqlAdapter.php. Your mentioned fix works.